# Application returns 500 error when Jmeter submits a POST with xml data

Tags: xml, jmeter

I am unable to root cause an issue I am getting while developing a jmeter script which is doing a query on an application(.net based).

I regularly Jmeter script recorder, and Corelation recorder in Jmeter on the same application, and I have not seen this issue till date.

So here are my observations:

1.When I started recording the application from Jmeter proxy server, the application works well for login and other transactions, but when I conduct the transaction which does a search, the application responds with " An error has occured".On the same browser if I run the flow manually with my system proxy(set as auto detetct) it runs well.

2.because of 1, I chose to record the script with Blazemeter extension and it recorded well, but when I . submit the request(through a corelated script) which does the search, the application returns 500 error(header) and the body says "An error has occurred".

3. Is see the request which is failing is submitting an XML in header, I see no header name, just value.
4. Following is the XML that is getting posted, 123 is the value I m entering for

search:

```html
<QueryToken><QueryItem NAME="Document" /><QueryCategories><QueryCategory NAME="CustomQuery"><QueryObject ID="110"/></QueryCategory></QueryCategories><QueryKeywords><QueryKeyword ID="149" OPERATOR="=" CONNECTOR="AND" ><![CDATA[123]]></QueryKeyword></QueryKeywords><QueryConstraints><QueryConstraint NAME="FromDate"></QueryConstraint><QueryConstraint NAME="ToDate"></QueryConstraint></QueryConstraints></QueryToken>
```

What could be the possible issue ?

I have tried posting the header data as raw, but see the same result.`enter code here`

Comment: Does the application use some dynamic token such as a token for csrf protection? In that case you might need to extract the token some of the previous responses (e.g. with Regular Expression Extractor) and use it in the request as variable.

Comment: Well I found the issue, it has got something to do with the way Jmeter proxy encodes and which is diff from Chrome(and may be other browsers too). Jmeter proxy was parsing some data in such a format that the server was unable to understand it and hence throwing a 500 error.So there is no solution to record the transaction through Jmeter proxy, it would always make server return a 500 error due to incorrect parsing.I manually coped the response in the Jmeter request and placed it in the body to make it work.